# Google+ login Winform using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, api, google-plus, google-signin

I'm working on a simple Winform application that allow to user to create an account with their Google account. I have check to the documentation of google Api but I don't how it can work with winforms.

The idea of the app is simple, I have 2 form:

1. ***Main Menu*** , with a button that show the second form.
2. ***WebBrowserForm***, this form contain a webBrowser to access to googleand get informations.

Please can you help me with a tutorial or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything directly out of the box that will do this for you.   The official [Google .net client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/) isn't going to give you the auth URI for you to display in the web browser control it automcatcly opens it in the users default web browser.

That doesn't mean this isn't something you cant do.   I have an application that does just that but I had to write it from the bottom up myself.

I have a very old tutorial on how I did it.   It starts with bulding the uri.

```
public static Uri GetAutenticationURI(string clientId, string redirectUri)
  {
  // separate more then one scope with a space
  string scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login email";   
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectUri))
   {
   redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
   }
 string oauth = string.Format("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&scope={2}&response_type=code", clientId, redirectUri, scopes);
return new Uri(oauth);
  }
```

The full tutorial [Google API and Oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-api-and-oath2/)

All that is going to do is get you authentication once you have your refresh token for your user you just save that then you can access the data again.  Your going to have to check the documentation on what ever APIs you want to request data from just tack your access token on the end of each request access_token=mytoken  or add it to the header of the request.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have i try the code in the tutorial , it show me google authentification page but when when i click on accept, it doesn't return nothing ?

Comment: it should load a new window where you will need to grab the authentication code.   Its a simple HTTP get so you can test it by placing the URL in a browser window.  try debugging your way though the document complete.

Comment: When i debbug it show me an exeception "out of range" in the method "webbrowser1_DocumentCompleted()" ?

Comment: That is an extremely old article I suspect your going to have to play with it to get it to work.

Comment: Can you help me please, because i have tried all the last weekend but it's not working, there is a lot of exceptions

Comment: That is the only tutorial I know of.   Most people use the Client library because its easer.   Doing this yourself is going to require that you debug your errors.